# Sunspot solr rake issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot-solr

When I try to rake command I get this error.
I have one application where solr runs properly, now I am trying to build a new application using solr I am unable to proceed

```
rake sunspot:install --trace

rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/object/to_json
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot_rails.rb:4:in `require'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot_rails.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/home/vaibhav/Mirraw/testing_solr/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vaibhav/Mirraw/testing_solr/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/vaibhav/Mirraw/testing_solr/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Here is my gem file,

> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> ```
> gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
>
> gem 'sqlite3'
>
> gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
>
> gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
>
> gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
>
> gem 'jquery-rails'
>
> gem 'turbolinks'
>
> gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
>
> gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
>
> gem 'sunspot_rails'
>
>
> group :development, :test do
>   gem 'byebug'
>
>   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
>
>   gem 'spring'
>
> end
> ```

Does anyone has any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a [known problem](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/555). The problem is that Rails 4.1 renamed a file in `ActiveSupport` core extensions and `sunspot_rails` is still trying to include the old file name. This was resolved in [this `sunspot_rails` commit](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/555/files) but it still [was not merged](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/2-0-stable/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot_rails.rb) to the stable 2.0 branch of the sunspot_rails gem.

Overall this gem seems to be quite abandoned so your only option is to try to use the `master` branch of the gem directly from github, not the stable 2.0 branch.

You can do it by updating your Gemfile so that instead of:

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
```

it will say:

```
gem 'sunspot_rails :github => 'sunspot/sunspot'
```

See more explanation [here](http://bundler.io/git.html).